# Seeking neighborhood boundaries for Saudi Arabia?

Tags: data, saudi-arabia

I currently have set of coordinates (lat,lon) that I would like to associate with neighborhoods or districts in Saudi Arabia. Therefore,I might be looking for neighborhood boundaries (polygons coordinates). What would be the best way to achieve this? I do not mind paid services, but of course I would prefer open/free services if possible.

Edit: searching in Google Maps selects the district boundaries, but I couldn't download this polygon using their API.

Comment: Have you looked at GADM? http://www.gadm.org/country

Comment: This is on the administrative area level and not district/neighborhood level.

Comment: For Riyadh (the capital) wikimapia is pretty good. I validated  the boundaries of 164 districts and it seems pretty accurate. However, the rest of the cities are a bit more tricky.

Comment: I still can’t figure a way that i can get geojson coordinates of neighborhoods boundaries in saudi arabia, can someone guide please ?

Answer (score 1):

You could check out if http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/ or http://www.weogeo.com/ has the data you want.

Comment: I contacted Weogeo to see if they have it. Natural earth don't seem to have them.